# Nexpose Kali Linux Install Not Working NeXpose security console exited with code 0

Tags: rapid7, nexpose

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mf8md.png)- this is the error code shown when i run ./nsc.sh in a root terminal, nexpose worked properly on first install and i was able to acess localhost:3780 with no issues but after a system reboot it did not work, i already tried restarting services including nexpseconsole and disabling postgresql on start up aswell as disabling nexposeconsole on start up

- `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] Product Version:                 6.6.202`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] Current directory:               /opt/rapid7/nexpose/nsc`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] User name:                       root`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] Super user:                      Yes`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] Computer name:                   2603-7081-233c-0100-6e88-14ff-feb6-b728`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] Host Address:                    127.0.1.1`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] Host FQDN:                       2603-7081-233c-0100-6e88-14ff-feb6-b728.res6.spectrum.com`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] Operating system:                Debian Linux kali-rolling`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] CPU speed:                       1395MHz`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] Number of CPUs:                  4`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] Total memory:                    7.6 GB`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] Available memory:                630.8 MB`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] Total disk space:                290.4 GB`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] Available disk space:            102.5 GB`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] Disk space used by installation: 3.3 GB`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] Disk space used by scans:        0 bytes`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] Disk space used by database:     109.9 MB`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] Disk space used by reports:      0 bytes`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] Disk space used by backups:      0 bytes`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] JVM name:                        OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] JVM vendor:                      Azul Systems, Inc.`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] JVM version:                     25.372-b07`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] JVM started:                     2023-07-05 01:07 GMT`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] Running interactively under super-user: root.`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [WARN] System is running low on memory: 7814MB total (629MB free)`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] Initializing JDBC drivers.`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:28 [INFO] Loading configuration...`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:29 [INFO] Initializing license manager...`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:29 [WARN] No valid licenses were found. This will prevent site modification and the running of scans.`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:29 [INFO] Initializing maintenance manager...`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:29 [INFO] Initializing crypto subsystem...`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:29 [INFO] Initializing plugins...`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:29 [INFO] Initializing authentication services...`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:29 [INFO] Initializing web server...`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:29 [INFO] Configuring web server.`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:30 [INFO] Generating skin: /opt/rapid7/nexpose/nsc/htroot/scripts/nexpose-skin.js`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:30 [INFO] Generating feature set: /opt/rapid7/nexpose/nsc/htroot/scripts/nexpose-features.js`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:30 [INFO] Context loader config file is jar:file:/opt/rapid7/nexpose/nsc/lib/nsc.jar!/META-INF/context.xml`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [INFO] Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-3780"]`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [ERROR] Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-3780"]`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [ERROR] Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-3780]]`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [ERROR] A critical error occurred during initialization`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [INFO] Adding maintenance task NexposeRecovery`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [INFO] Reinitializing web server for maintenance mode...`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [INFO] Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-3780"]`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [INFO] Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-3780"]`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [INFO] Accepting web server logins.`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [INFO] Found a pending maintenance task: NexposeRecovery`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [INFO] Entering maintenance mode, only administrator logins permitted.`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [INFO] Maintenance Task Started`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [INFO] Accepting console commands.`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [ERROR] Error during server initialization.`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [INFO] Shutting down immediately`
- 
- `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [WARN] Error stopping quartz schedulers.`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [INFO] Shutting down web server...`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [INFO] Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-3780"]`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [INFO] Stopping service Tomcat`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [ERROR] Problem shutting down Tomcat`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [INFO] Web server stopped`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [INFO] removing scheduled risk and history updater jobs`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [INFO] Shutting down extension manager`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [INFO] Extension manager shutdown successful.`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [INFO] Shutting down config manager`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [INFO] Shutting down crypto system`
- `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [WARN] Error stopping connection scheduler.`
- 
- 
- `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [INFO] Shutting down daemon manager`
- 
- 
- `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [WARN] Error shutting down database.`
- 
- 
- `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [INFO] Shutting down command console`
- 
- 
- `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [INFO] Shutting down web server...`
- 
- 
- `` NeXpose security console exited with code 0` ``
- 
- 
- `` i already reinstalled nexpose my kali is up to date, i disabled pstgresql the second install. i ran every command with sudo, i got nexpose to open up the first install and work but after i shut my machine down it never worked again.` i cant seem to find any documentation online towards this issue and ive already tried most things i can find any help wuld ``

  1. `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] Product Version: 6.6.202`
  2. `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] Current directory: /opt/rapid7/nexpose/nsc`
  3. `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] User name: root`
  4. `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] Super user: Yes`
  5. `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] Computer name: 2603-7081-233c-0100-6e88-14ff-feb6-b728`
  6. `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] Host Address: 127.0.1.1`
  7. `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] Host FQDN: 2603-7081-233c-0100-6e88-14ff-feb6-b728.res6.spectrum.com`
  8. `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] Operating system: Debian Linux kali-rolling`
  9. `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] CPU speed: 1395MHz`
  10. `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] Number of CPUs: 4`
  11. `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] Total memory: 7.6 GB`
  12. `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] Available memory: 630.8 MB`
  13. `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] Total disk space: 290.4 GB`
  14. `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] Available disk space: 102.5 GB`
  15. `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] Disk space used by installation: 3.3 GB`
  16. `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] Disk space used by scans: 0 bytes`
  17. `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] Disk space used by database: 109.9 MB`
  18. `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] Disk space used by reports: 0 bytes`
  19. `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] Disk space used by backups: 0 bytes`
  20. `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] JVM name: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM`
  21. `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] JVM vendor: Azul Systems, Inc.`
  22. `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] JVM version: 25.372-b07`
  23. `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] JVM started: 2023-07-05 01:07 GMT`
  24. `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] Running interactively under super-user: root.`
  25. `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [WARN] System is running low on memory: 7814MB total (629MB free)`
  26. `2023-07-04T21:07:27 [INFO] Initializing JDBC drivers.`
  27. `2023-07-04T21:07:28 [INFO] Loading configuration...`
  28. `2023-07-04T21:07:29 [INFO] Initializing license manager...`
  29. `2023-07-04T21:07:29 [WARN] No valid licenses were found. This will prevent site modification and the running of scans.`
  30. `2023-07-04T21:07:29 [INFO] Initializing maintenance manager...`
  31. `2023-07-04T21:07:29 [INFO] Initializing crypto subsystem...`
  32. `2023-07-04T21:07:29 [INFO] Initializing plugins...`
  33. `2023-07-04T21:07:29 [INFO] Initializing authentication services...`
  34. `2023-07-04T21:07:29 [INFO] Initializing web server...`
  35. `2023-07-04T21:07:29 [INFO] Configuring web server.`
  36. `2023-07-04T21:07:30 [INFO] Generating skin: /opt/rapid7/nexpose/nsc/htroot/scripts/nexpose-skin.js`
  37. `2023-07-04T21:07:30 [INFO] Generating feature set: /opt/rapid7/nexpose/nsc/htroot/scripts/nexpose-features.js`
  38. `2023-07-04T21:07:30 [INFO] Context loader config file is jar:file:/opt/rapid7/nexpose/nsc/lib/nsc.jar!/META-INF/context.xml`
  39. `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [INFO] Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-3780"]`
  40. `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [ERROR] Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-3780"]`
  41. `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [ERROR] Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-3780]]`
  42. `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [ERROR] A critical error occurred during initialization`
  43. `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [INFO] Adding maintenance task NexposeRecovery`
  44. `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [INFO] Reinitializing web server for maintenance mode...`
  45. `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [INFO] Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-3780"]`
  46. `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [INFO] Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-3780"]`
  47. `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [INFO] Accepting web server logins.`
  48. `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [INFO] Found a pending maintenance task: NexposeRecovery`
  49. `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [INFO] Entering maintenance mode, only administrator logins permitted.`
  50. `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [INFO] Maintenance Task Started`
  51. `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [INFO] Accepting console commands.`
  52. `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [ERROR] Error during server initialization.`
  53. `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [INFO] Shutting down immediately`
  54. 
  55. `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [WARN] Error stopping quartz schedulers.`
  56. `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [INFO] Shutting down web server...`
  57. `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [INFO] Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-3780"]`
  58. `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [INFO] Stopping service Tomcat`
  59. `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [ERROR] Problem shutting down Tomcat`
  60. `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [INFO] Web server stopped`
  61. `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [INFO] removing scheduled risk and history updater jobs`
  62. `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [INFO] Shutting down extension manager`
  63. `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [INFO] Extension manager shutdown successful.`
  64. `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [INFO] Shutting down config manager`
  65. `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [INFO] Shutting down crypto system`
  66. `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [WARN] Error stopping connection scheduler.`
  67. 
  68. 
  69. `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [INFO] Shutting down daemon manager`
  70. 
  71. 
  72. `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [WARN] Error shutting down database.`
  73. 
  74. 
  75. `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [INFO] Shutting down command console`
  76. 
  77. 
  78. `2023-07-04T21:07:32 [INFO] Shutting down web server...`
  79. 
  80. 
  81. `` NeXpose security console exited with code 0` ``
  82. 
  83. 
  84. `` i already reinstalled nexpose my kali is up to date, i disabled pstgresql the second install. i ran every command with sudo, i got nexpose to open up the first install and work but after i shut my machine down it never worked again.` ``

i reinstalled already while disabling pstgresql before the install, nexpose worked fine once and then never worked again

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my Kali Linux.

Turns out I was out of storage. I believe creating/freeing up storage space will fix this error. Run the nsc.sh script once you have created storage space (30gb should do).

Ultimately, make sure your system has enough resources as suggested by Nexpose.